# How to Send blowfish key over Network in java

Tags: java, network-programming, encryption-symmetric

I have a Java Project to Authenticate images over a wireless network. I am using blowfish for encryption of images. The problem I am facing is how to send the blowfish symmetric key to the receiver so that he can decrypt the image. I am relatively new to cryptography.Please include the code snippet to illustrate the same.

package ClientModule;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.swing.*;

 public class ImageEncryption_Client
{
     KeyGenerator keyGenerator = null;
    public static SecretKey secretKey = null;
 public static Cipher cipher = null;

     ImageEncryption_Client(){
    try {
            /**
             * Create a Blowfish key
             */
            keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
            secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
            System.out.println(secretKey.toString());

            /**
             * Create an instance of cipher mentioning the name of algorithm
             *     - Blowfish
             */
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Blowfish");
            System.out.println(cipher.toString());
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private void encrypt(String srcPath, String destPath)
    {
        File rawFile = new File(srcPath);
        File encryptedFile = new File(destPath);
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;
        try {
            /**
             * Initialize the cipher for encryption
             */
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            /**
             * Initialize input and output streams
             */
            inStream = new FileInputStream(rawFile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outStream.write(cipher.update(buffer, 0, len));
                outStream.flush();
            }
            outStream.write(cipher.doFinal());
            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An Exception Occurred","Exception",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An Exception Occurred","Exception",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An Exception Occurred","Exception",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An Exception Occurred","Exception",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"An Exception Occurred","Exception",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    void enc(String filename)//, String dir)
    {

        String fileToEncrypt = filename;
        String arr[]=filename.split("\\.");

        String encryptedFile = arr[0]+"_encrypted."+arr[1];

        String directoryPath = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\";

        encrypt(directoryPath + fileToEncrypt,
                directoryPath + encryptedFile);
    }
    public static void main(String... kkk)
     {
        new ImageEncryption_Client().enc("Koala.jpg");//,"");
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

First off, I wouldn't tread into this area without doing a bit more research or consulting a security expert.

One really good resource on crypto specifically targeted at developers is: https://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography_engineering/

Now on to answering your question. I would first question whether you actually need to do key-exchange or whether you could get away with setting up a pre-shared secret / key pair on both sides.

**Key Exchange**

Key exchange is the class of problem you're asking about. There are many implementations:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_exchange

Diffie Hellman is a classic approach which is popular in SSL and TLS:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

A java implementation example of Diffie Hellman can be found here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/CryptoSpec.html#DH2Ex

**Pre-shared Key**

Key exchange is complex and requires that you own both sides of the communication. Another approach would be to place a shared secret on both ends of the communication. The simplest approach would be to share a symmetric key. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_secret

A slightly more secure approach would be to use asymmetric keys (public key crypto) where each side generates it's own public private key pair and then you pre-share the public key with the other end. So in the classic example where Alice and Bob want to communicate securely, Alice would give Bob her public key and Bob would encrypt all data sent to Alice with her public key. She could then decrypt it with her private key. This approach has the advantage where if any one side is compromised the attacker can't read messages encrypted for the other side. More details are outlined here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

A third and slightly more granular approach building on the last one would be to generate a symmetric key per image and encrypt the image with that key. Then encrypt the symmetric key with the public key of the party you're sending the data to. When sending the image over the wire you'd include the encrypted key and the encrypted image. This model is useful because symmetric encryption is faster and better suited for large files like images but combining them in this way you still get the benefits of using public key crypto to protect the transport.

If you happen to be doing this up on AWS, their KMS service would make it very easy to have a shared encryption key across servers. They also use a multi-level crypto approach similar to the last model but in this case the master key is stored on a hardware security module (HSM), which has the added benefit that the master key is never known and can never be pulled off the chip it lives on:
http://aws.amazon.com/kms/